# Compare two databases using Django and create a third one with the result?

Tags: python, sql, django

I am developing a website using Django and I need to compare two databases.

With the differences found I want to create a third table in memory to later use. To give you an idea.

```
Table1:
------------
|ID | Name |
------------
| 1 |  A   |
------------
| 2 |  B   |
------------
| 3 |  C   |
------------

Table2:
------------
|ID | Name |
------------
| 1 |  A   |
------------
| 2 |  R   |
------------
| 3 |  G   |
------------

ResultTable:
------------
|ID | Name |
------------
| 2 |  R   |
------------
| 3 |  G   |
------------
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can define [multiple database connections](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/multi-db/) in Django. Then, you can issue queries on each connection, and use [difflib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html) to get differences in rows between the results, and put them into another table in another database.